# What are these VMWare instructions actually doing? (Disabling device guard and removing EFI variables)

Tags: vmware-player

I'm trying to run a VMWare VM on my windows 10 device, but am getting an error that it is not compatible with Device Guard. I was directed to this page: https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2146361

What are the instructions there actually doing?

> ```
> mountvol X: /s
> copy %WINDIR%\System32\SecConfig.efi X:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi /Y
> bcdedit /create {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} /d "DebugTool" /application osloader
> bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} path "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi"
> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} bootsequence {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}
> bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} loadoptions DISABLE-LSA-ISO,DISABLE-VBS
> bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} device partition=X:
> mountvol X: /d
> ```
>
> Note: Ensure X is an unused drive, otherwise change to another drive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> mountvol X: /s

Mounts the EFI system partition on to Drive X:

> copy %WINDIR%\System32\SecConfig.efi X:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi /Y

Copies the `C:\Windows\System32\SecConfig.efi` to `X:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi` overwriting the file if it exists. This file is the boot image for windows' security configuration tool.

> bcdedit /create {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} /d "DebugTool" 
>   /application osloader

Creates a new option in the boot menu called "DebugTool" with the ID `{0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}`

> bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} path "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi"

Sets the boot option you created to boot to `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi`

> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} bootsequence {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}

Tells the boot manager to make the new entry the default for the next reboot, after that reboot it should go back to normal boot.

> bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} loadoptions DISABLE-LSA-ISO,DISABLE-VBS

Tells the bootloader to pass the options `DISABLE-LSA-ISO,DISABLE-VBS` to the efi file when it launches the file.

> bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} device partition=X:

Sets the partition for the booted drive to the X: drive.

> mountvol X: /d

Unmounts the X Drive.

Now when you next reboot your computer it should restart with the "Debug Tool" option, every reboot after that should boot back in to normal windows.

Comment: Thanks! So if I want, I can boot to a configuration that still had the Device Guard enabled(I would still need to enable it in GPEDIT)? Additionally, when they say that I should use an unused drive, does this mean a blank drive or a drive not used by windows?

Comment: you would turn it off and on by going in to "DebugTool" in the boot menu. When it says a unused drive it just means a letter that is not currently mapped by windows.

Comment: This helps to figure out how to set it all back. Thanks.

Comment: @TatianaRacheva if you want to remove it all you need to do is `bcdedit /delete {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}`

Comment: I don't remember if I figured out to delete that or not, but my system is back to normal :D