# VMware Workstation can be run after disabling Device/Credential Guard

Tags: windows-10, vmware, vmware-workstation, sandbox

I tried to install Windows Sandbox on my Windows 10 Home  installation.  Now that I have done that, VMWare Workstation, does not work and I have started to recieve the following error "**VMware Workstation can be run after disabling Device/Credential Guard**"

What can I do to get VMWare Workstaiton working again?

Comment: Download the [DG Readiness Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337) and provide the output of `DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.5.ps1 -Ready` by editing your question.  I will be unable to submit my answer without this information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtual Machine is not running in windows 10 Home](https://superuser.com/questions/1480801/virtual-machine-is-not-running-in-windows-10-home)

Answer (score 2):

> I try to install windows sandbox in my windows 10 home

**Windows Sandbox cannot be enabled on Windows 10 Home.**  The workaround you most likely used, does not even work, and has never actually worked.  However, when you attempted to enable Windows Sandbox, it also enabled Credential Guard and Device Guard.

The first thing you need to backup any critical files you cannot live without.  Depending on the state of your system you might decide it's time to simply reinstall Windows 10 Home.  An alternative is to upgrade to Windows 10 Professional so you can Enable Windows Sandbox then disable it properly.  **The following suggestion was written against an assumption that Windows Sandbox was properly enabled and not left in a broken state due to a workaround solution on Windows 10 Home.**

> 1. Windows Security -->> Device Security -->> Core Isolation -->> Memory Integrity -->> Select Off
> 2. Since you are using Windows 10 Home you will have to install the [group policy editor](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i) to perform next step.
> 3. Set Local Computer Policy ->> Computer Configuration ->> Administrative Templates ->> System - Device Guard ->> Turn on
>    Virtualization to **Disabled**
> 4. Be sure **Enabled with UEFI lock** is not enabled.
> 5. Download the [Device Guard and Credential Guard Hardware Readiness Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337) and run the following command as an Administrator.
>
>    - DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.6.ps1 -Disable -AutoReboot
> 6. You also need to disable both **Hyper-V** and **Windows Sandbox.**  The following commands assume you are running **Windows 10 Professional** or **Windows 10 Enterprise**.
>
>    - Dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:”Containers-DisposableClientVM” -All
>    - Dism /online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:”Containers-DisposableClientVM”
>    - Dism /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
> 7. You should reboot your machine at this point

Source:

- [Windows Sandbox Feature enables windows defender credential guard feature sets. Does not play well with VMware Workstation](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/604906)
- [Manage Windows Defender Credential Guard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/credential-guard-manage)
- [VMware Player and Device/Credential Guard are not compatible](https://superuser.com/questions/1133289/vmware-player-and-device-credential-guard-are-not-compatible?rq=1)

Comment: There are some additional BCD enteries that might exist, due to the unknown state of your system, I have not included those commands. The following solution **should** work but due to the workaround you use, you might have made it impossible, to reverse the changes you have made.  I know the problem is due to Credential Guard and/or Device Guard currently being enabled. This absolutely happened when you attempted to enable Windows Sandbox. Due to the fact the only Windows Sandbox on Windows 10 Home workaround, i know that exists does not even work, I cannot guarantee the sucess of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44306227/1454173), simply run this in cmd as administrator and then **reboot**

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.