# VMware Workstation and Defender Credential Guard (without HyperV)

Tags: vmware, hyper-v, vmware-workstation, windows-defender

I'm trying to run a virtual machine in VMware Workstation Pro 15 and I get an error message saying that I need to first disable Defender Device/Credential Guard.  I didn't know this was enabled so I did a bit of reading up on it and everything I've come across mentions that this is enabled along with HyperV.  However, I don't use or have HyperV installed and most of the instructions I've come across talk about disabling HyperV to get around this error.  If HyperV is not installed what would be the correct process for disabling Defender Device/Credential Guard and also wondering why would this be enabled in the first place if HyperV was never installed before.

Comment: Any software or feature that uses the virtualization extension is not compatible with VMWare.  If you are getting this error message it means that is the case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1](https://superuser.com/questions/1466635/vmware-workstation-can-be-run-after-disabling-device-credential-guard) [2](https://superuser.com/questions/1442766/virtualbox-fails-to-start-with-verr-nem-vm-create-failed/1485919#1485919) [3](https://superuser.com/questions/1480801/virtual-machine-is-not-running-in-windows-10-home/1480825#1480825)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some of the suggested similar questions I learned that Windows Sandbox uses HyperV under the hood.  The solution for my situation ended up being to simply uninstall Windows Sandbox via Optional Windows Features and reboot twice.  Not other configuration or changes were required.

Comment: As in [here][1], simply run this in cmd as administrator and then **reboot**

    bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44306227/1454173