# So, apparently I have a hypervisor when I don't?

Tags: hyper-v, hypervisor

Just got a Surface Pro 7 and been pretty happy with it. However, when I tried to run a an Android emulator, I received an error saying that Hyper-V was enabled.

I went to go disable it, and here's where I ran into issues.

I undoubtedly have some form of hypervisor running.

System Info page shows that there is a hypervisor:

[image: System Info page shows that there is a hypervisor.]

However, from control panel in the "turn windows features on and off" panel, Hyper-V is not even an entry. Related items like Virtual Machine Platform and Windows Hypervisor Platform are unchecked.

Beginning of the list:

[image: Beginning of the list]

End of the list:

[image: End of the list]

Furthermore, trying to run the command

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor
```

in an elevated Powershell window following the instructions of [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/virtualization-apps-not-work-with-hyper-v) gives an error saying that the specified feature is not found.

Powershell fails:

[image: Powershell fails]

I don't have any additional security software installed apart from Windows Defender. I'm trying to run MuMu emulator.
I'm frankly at a loss as to what else to try at this point.

I know Microsoft is paranoid about security since IIRC they cited a potential vulnerability as their reason for not including Thunderbolt, so do Surface products have some sort of baked-in hypervisor functionality or something?

Comment: Check Windows Defender and make sure that Core Isolation is disabled. It can steal virtual machine extensions. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-protection-in-windows-security-afa11526-de57-b1c5-599f-3a4c6a61c5e2

Comment: Surface Pro devices come with hardware virtualization enabled.  It actually cannot be disabled.  You don’t mention what Android emulator your attempting to use.  You also don’t indicate what security products you have installed

Comment: @Ramhound No security products installed aside from the baked in Windows Defender. I'm using MuMu emulator, which I haven't had issues with on my main machine.

Info also added to OP

Comment: @Mokubai tried that in conjunction with Señor CMasMas's answer to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtual Machine is not running in windows 10 Home](https://superuser.com/questions/1480801/virtual-machine-is-not-running-in-windows-10-home)

Comment: I removed the Answer from your question, it should be posted separately (as you already did) and not mixed inside the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found. I blame MuMu devs being lazy and assuming any virtualization based issue was because of Hyper-V. The issue was not Hyper-V as the error message claimed but rather hardware virtualization being used by Memory Isolation in Windows Defender as well as Device Guard in Windows.

For any users googling around with a similar issue, I'll leave disabling Memory Isolation to the numerous other articles.

To disable Device Guard, open Regedit, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard`, then set the value for `EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity` to `0`.

Finally, in an elevated command prompt use the command:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Comment: there is no entry under the name `EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity` for me on Win10.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

In an elevated Command Prompt write this :

To disable:
`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

To enable:
`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`

Just used it today to get VirtualBox working again after Microsoft wiped out my bcd boot record on an upgrade.

I got the information from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496116/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-command-line)

Comment: Tried that, didn't work unfortunately. Appreciate the attempt though.

Comment: Look deeper into the post then.  Follow the directions to copy and disable one of the bcd profiles.  I just did this yesterday with 20H2 with success.. I don't care about the points.  I just want your stuff to work for you.  What did it say?  Does it show `hypervisorlaunchtype    Off` when you type bcdedit?  If so, you have another problem not related to hypervisor.  Good luck.

Comment: Alrighty, looks like the MuMu devs were lazy and just assumed any issues involving virtualization already being in use were caused by Hyper-V.

While I did not find my solution in the linked post, searching for information on hardware virtualization on the Surface in general pointed me to turning off Device Guard in the registry.

This, in conjunction with disabling Memory Isolation solved me issue.

Comment: @ConfusedGachaGamer - You should submit a detailed answer instead of answering your own question with a temporary comment. Otherwise, I can find an existing answer about VirtualBox, which mentions Device Guard

Comment: @Ramhound Cool I'll go do that.