# ReEnabling Hypervisor

Tags: command-line, vmware, android-studio, hypervisor

Basically I had to use vmware for another project previously and disabled hypervisor through these commands in this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGpv2Dvzyeg

**bcdedit /create {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} /d "DebugTool" /application osloader**

**bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} path "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi"**

**bcdedit /set {bootmgr} bootsequence {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}**

**bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} loadoptions DISABLE-LSA-ISO,DISABLE-VBS**

**bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off**

I currently need to use android studio emulation and have to turn it back on.

Can anyone help me reverse this?

I am using a ryzen processor which is what caused me all this headache in the first place

I've tried asking this question on stackoverflow but got no replies I found this link [What are these VMWare instructions actually doing? (Disabling device guard and removing EFI variables)](https://superuser.com/questions/1124753/what-are-these-vmware-instructions-actually-doing-disabling-device-guard-and-r) and thought maybe this is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

This post helped me [How to re-enable Win 10 hypervisor after Android Studio 3 disabled it](https://superuser.com/questions/1336924/how-to-re-enable-win-10-hypervisor-after-android-studio-3-disabled-it?rq=1)

**bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto**